# When to use hints in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimizer-hints

I have gone through some documentation on the net and using hints is mostly discouraged. I still have doubts about this. Can hints be really useful in production specially when same query is used by hundreds of different customer.

Is hint only useful when we know the number of records that are present in the tables? I am using **leading** in my query and it gives faster results when the data is very large but the performance is not that great when the records fetched are less.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525486/when-to-use-oracle-hints) by David is very good but I would appreciate if someone clarified this in more details.

Comment: The basic idea is that the optimizer is fairly smart, and uses statistics about your table to decide which query strategy to execute.  If you use a hint, e.g. force an index, then later on when your data changes the plan executed might not be the best one.  That being said, there are cases where using a hint is appropriate, but this is a relatively rare thing.

Comment: This cannot be answered without a substantial article and many examples, is it really appropriate here?

Comment: Questions posted to SO that can be answered only with opinions are discouraged. Look for books, blog entries, and the like where the author shows *all* of his work and provides performance statistics that prove one way is better for the givens.

Answer (score 2):

Most hints are a way of communicating our intent to the optimizer. For instance, the `leading` hint you mention means *join tables in this order*. Why is this necessary? Often it's because the optimal join order is not obvious, because the query is badly written or the database statistics are inaccurate.

So one use of  hints such as `leading` is to figure out the best execution path, then to figure out why the database doesn't choose that plan without the hint. Does gathering fresh statistics solve the problem? Does rewriting the FROM clause solve the problem? If so, we can remove the hints and deploy the naked SQL.

Some times there are times where we cannot resolve this conundrum, and have to keep the hints in Production. However this should be a rare exception. Oracle have had lots of very clever people working on the Cost-Based Optimizer for many years, so its decisions are usually better than ours.

But there are other hints we would not blink to see in Production. `append` is often crucial for tuning bulk inserts. `driving_site` can be vital in tuning distributed queries.

Conversely other hints are almost always abused. Yes `parallel`, I'm talking about you. Blindly putting `/*+ parallel (t23, 16) */` will probably not make your query run sixteen times faster, and not infrequently will result in *slower* retrieval than a single-threaded execution.

So, in short, there is no universally applicable advice to when we should use hints. The key things are:

1. understand how the database works, and especially how the cost-based optimizer works;
2. understand what each hint does;
3. test hinted queries in a proper tuning environment with Production-equivalent data.

Obviously the best place to start is [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/hintsref.htm#PFGRF005). However, if you feel like spending some money, Jonathan Lewis's book on [the Cost-Based Optimizer](https://www.apress.com/la/book/9781590596364) is the best investment you could make.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't just rephrase that, so I will paste it here 
(it's a brief explanation as of **"When Not To Use Hints"**, that I had bookmarked):

In summary, don’t use hints when

1. What the hint does is poorly understood, which is of course not limited to the (ab)use of hints;
2. You have not looked at the root cause of bad SQL code and thus not yet tapped into the vast expertise and experience of your DBA in tuning the database;
3. Your statistics are out of date, and you can refresh the statistics more frequently or even fix the statistics to a representative state;
4. You do not intend to check the correctness of the hints in your statements on a regular basis, which means that, when statistics change, the hint may be woefully inadequate;
5. You have no intention of documenting the use of hints anyway.

Source link [here](http://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sql/hints/when-not-to-use.html).

I can summarize this as: The use of hints is not only a last resort, but also a lack of knowledge on the root cause of the issue. The CBO (Cost Based Optimizer) does an excellent job, if you just ensure some basics for it. Those include:

1. Fresh statistics
   1.1. Index statistics
   1.2. Table statistics
   1.3. Histograms
2. Correct `JOIN` conditions and `INDEX` utilization
3. Correct Database settings

This article here is worth reading:
[Top 10 Reasons for poor Oracle performance](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_top_reasons_poor_performance.htm)

*Presented by non other, but Mr. Donald Burleson.*

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In general hints should be used only exceptional, I know following situations where they make sense:

**Workaround for Oracle bugs**

Example: Once for a SELECT statement I got an error `ORA-01795: maximum expression number in list - 1000`, although the query did not contain an [IN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/expression.htm#sthref1967) expression at all.

Problem was: The queried table contains more than 1000 (sub-) partitions and Oracle did a transformation of my query. Using the (undocumented) hint `NO_EXPAND_TABLE` solved the issue.

**Datewarehouse application while staging**

While staging you can have significant changes on your data where the table/index statistics are not aware about as statistics are gathered only once a week by default. If you know your data structure then hints could be useful as they are faster than running `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(...)` manually all the time in between your operations. On the other hand you can run `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS()` even for single columns which might be the better approach.

**Online Application Upgrade Hints**

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#CHDIFFJE):

> The `CHANGE_DUPKEY_ERROR_INDEX`, `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`, and
>   `RETRY_ON_ROW_CHANGE` hints are unlike other hints in that they have a
>   semantic effect. The general philosophy explained in "Hints" does not
>   apply for these three hints.